# How to share data between JQuery in the Header section with a Javascript in the Body section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I downloaded an awesome JQuery scripts/plugin and I am trying to get the script incorporated into my project. I want to be able to share data or value from JQuery in the Head section of the HTML file to the Javascript in the Body of HTML file. I've tried different ways after reading up many threads and forums and stackoverflow questions but none seem to help me. I keep getting `X function is not defined`. Have a look at this sample code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Testing</title>
    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/raphael-min.js"></script>

<script src="/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.svg.common.core.js" ></script>
<script src="/RGraph/libraries/RGraph.svg.line.js" ></script>
<script src="/RGraph/demos/demos.js" ></script>

<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
      var socket = io();
    
      socket.on('sensor_values',function(msg){
         
            line.update(msg[0].value); //<------- This function is defined in the Javascript below
            
        });
});
</script> 

</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 750px; height: 300px" id="chart-container"></div>        

<script>
    iteration = 0;
    data      = [];
    labels    = [
        '','','','','','','','','','',
        '','','','','','','','','',''
    ];

    line = new RGraph.SVG.Line({
        id: 'chart-container',
        data: [data],
        options: {
            marginInner: 0,
            title: 'GasBoss Demo Chart',
            xaxisLabels: labels,
            xaxisColor: '#aaa',
            yaxis: false,
            backgroundGridColor: '#eee',
            backgroundGridVlines: false,
            backgroundGridBorder: false,
            colors: ['#00c','#c00'],
            linewidth: 1,
            tickmarksStyle: 'filledcircle'
        }
    }).draw();

    function update (svalue) //<-------this is the function I am trying to call in the JQuery code above
    {
        if (iteration === 0) {
            line.originalData[0] = RGraph.SVG.arrayPad([],20);                
        }
        
        line.originalData[0].push(svalue);
        line.originalData[0].shift();

        line.properties.xaxisLabels.push(iteration + 1)
        line.properties.xaxisLabels.shift();

        RGraph.SVG.redraw();
        
        iteration++;
    }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

When start typing the function name in the JQuery section, it pops up a context menu with the name of the function for me to select. That means to me that JQuery is able to see all the functions and variables from within Javascript code, but it still raises Update is not a function. Why? and how do you share or pass data between JQuery and Javascript as described above in their respective place within the HTML file.

Comment: You define an `update` function, but you are calling `line.update`.

Comment: Just call `update(msg[0].value);` - update is not a method of `line`, it's a separate function

Comment: Should I just go ahead and delete the question?